# How to label column inputs "low - medium -high"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data in 1 min intervals, I want to group the column inputs as low-medium-high.

If between 0-33: low
If between 33-67: medium
If between 67-100: high

from this:

```
     df
    timestamp    val1                           
    2019-06-05  40  
    2019-06-05  12  
    2019-06-05  78
```

to this:

```
df
timestamp    val1                           
2019-06-05  medium  
2019-06-05  low
2019-06-05  high
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pandas.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

```
bins = [0, 33, 67, 100]
labels = ['low', 'meduin', 'high']
df['val1'] = pd.cut(df['val1'], bins, labels=labels)
print(df)
```

---

```
    timestamp    val1
0  2019-06-05  meduin
1  2019-06-05     low
2  2019-06-05    high
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
df['val1'] = df['val1'].apply(lambda x:  'low' if 0 < x < 33 else 'med' if 33 <= x < 66 else 'high')
```

Comment: Much simpler with `pandas.cut` but this is likely a duplicate anyway.

Comment: @BigBen Great! I'm still learning. I'm going to keep `cut` in my back pocket. I was hoping there was a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `numpy.where`:

```
df['val1'] = np.where(df.val1 <= 33, 'low',
  np.where(df.val1 < 67, 'medium', 'high'))
```

Output:

```
    timestamp    val1
0  2019-06-05  medium
1  2019-06-05     low
2  2019-06-05    high
```